# Bookmark, TOC and Header show the right numbering of Ch, Sec and Subsec

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

My little test example is as follows

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    bookmarksdepth=2,
}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % ch=0,sec=1,subsec=2,subsubsec=3
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{} %% remove the word \chapter
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\LARGE\bfseries}{Lec~\arabic{chapter}~~}{0pt}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\S~\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\Roman{subsection}.}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
    {\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsubsection}}{1em}{}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Water}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Ocean}
\subsection{River}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Pond}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Brook}
\lipsum[1-3]

\chapter{Whale}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Shark}
\subsection{Carp}
\lipsum[1]
\subsubsection{Shrimp}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsubsection{Crab}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

As you can see, I want to the numbering of Ch, Sec and Subsec as

```
Lec 1
    SS 1.1
        I
        II
        III
        ...
    SS 1.2
        I
        II
        III
        ...
    ...
Lec 2
    SS 2.1
        I
        II
        III
        ...
    SS 2.2
        I
        II
        III
        ...
    ...
...
```

They are precisely presented in the text. However, the Bookmark, TOC and fancy-Header do not auto-update corresponding numbering, and simply show something like

```
1
    1.1
        1.1.1
2
    2.1
        2.1.1
```

How can I remedy these issues?

Comment: I tried your MWE but it gave the same numbers in the ToC as in the document itself. I think you need to look again at how you are specifying the division numbers. I have no experience with the `titlesec` package preferring the methods provided by the `memoir` class (a superset of the `book`, `report` and `article` classes).

Comment: Tks@PeterWilson, I will try the `memoir` class